# How to bind a controller action to a link that is clicked or hovered?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I have a problem connected with binding an action to a link. When I create a simple link (only a "text" reference), I am able to send the action to the controller and it works like a charm.

On the other hand, I am not able to do this when I want to make my flower element highlighted on hover and active state -> when I have a text (like in previous case) and corresponding part of the picture that gets highlighted on hover and click (pure SASS in this case).

Here is my hbs code:

```
<div id="flowers-list">
 <ul class="flowers">
  <li class="flower1">
    <a href="#/" {{action "selectFlower" "rose"}}>Rose</a>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Could you please give me a hint how to deal with this problem?

I have already tried adding `on=click` to my link, but it did not help.

Comment: Your hbs code works fine. http://ember-twiddle.com/7a76bc51aa5c4310a7c8

Comment: @Gaurav the problem was that this code works fine when I create a link like in your case. But when this url is connected with image (pretty simple css stuff) and reacts to hover and click, this stops working.

Comment: I can't read your mind. Please post your actual code and question then.

Answer (score 0):

To do it on hover, just change it to:

```
{{action "selectFlower" "rose" on="mouseEnter"}}
```